# Передача this(создаваемого объекта в конструкторе) в событие

Tags: javascript

```
function Cl(){
    this.name=100;
    this.view=function(){
        input=document.createElement('input');
        input.name='inputs';
        input.addEventListener('click',function(){console.log(this.name)})

        document.body.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
obj=new Cl;
obj.view();
```

Помогите вызвать  console.log(this.name) чтобы вывелось 100;Нужно обратится к объекту создаваемым конструктором.Расмотрю все варианты.Чем больше тем лучше.Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

или так:

```
input.addEventListener('click',function(){
    console.log(this.name)
}.bind(this))
```

или так:

```
function Cl(){
    var self = this;
    this.name=100;
    this.view=function(){
        ...
        input.addEventListener('click',function(){console.log(self.name)})
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Благодарен.Кто будет читать -http://learn.javascript.ru/bind-late#%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: вообще канонически bind вот:

    !function(){
        var _slice = Array.prototype.slice
        Function.prototype.bind = function(context){
            var args = _slice.call(arguments, 1),
            func = this;
            return function(){
               return func.apply(context, args.concat(_slice.call(arguments,0)));
            }
        }
    }()

Comment: Можно без `.bind(this)` т.к. вы и так передаете контекст, когда вешаете обработчик на элемент.

Comment: вообще-то контекст определяется во время вызова функции, а не её определения, или я неправильно понял вас

Comment: @Spectre я о этом: http://jsfiddle.net/2YAhD/

тут прикол в том, что функция-обработчик получает текущий элемент, на котором сработало событие, если мы используем addEventListener. А вот если это IE, то работает только attachEvent, который наоборот не умеет получать текущего элемента.

Comment: вот именно, ТС хотел чтобы контекстом был не елемент, на который вешают обработчик, а `obj`

Answer (score 2):

```
input.addEventListener('click',function(t){return function(){console.log(t.name)}}(this))
```

Comment: Благодарен